# Serving static files in secondary routes ("/route/secondary/route") Golang

Tags: go

In my root handle ("/") or clients handle ("/clients") the static files are correctly avaliable, and looking the network tab on chrome, i see the server request like this:

```
localhost:8080/static/file.example
```

But if i'm on the secondary handle ("/Clients/route"), don't work correctly, i see this:

```
localhost:8080/clients/static/file.example
```

The StripPrefix don't remove the "client" from the request.

```
func main() {
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/static"))))

http.HandleFunc("/", index)
http.HandleFunc("/clients", controllers.MostrarClientes)
http.HandleFunc("/clientes/route", controllers.MainIndex)

http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

-

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/leaflet/leaflet.css" />
```

-

File tree:

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uohCx.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an issue with the handler, it is an issue with your HTML link.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/leaflet/leaflet.css" />` is relative to the current URL.

That is to say, `static/leaflet/leaflet.css` will be appended to the current URL - when you are on your homepage this isn't an issue as it translates to `/static/leaflet/leaflet.css` but when you are on your clients page it turns into `/clients/static/leaflet/leaflet.css`.

The simple fix is just to add a leading `/` to your `href`:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/leaflet/leaflet.css" />`

This makes the URL absolute and it will be unaffected by visiting other pages of your website.